# Tensorflow delete element from each row based on index (negation of gather_nd)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

First, some background. I'm currently writing a custom TensorFlow 2.x preprocessing function for my data input pipeline. Eventually I'll `map` on a batch. Essentially, the function takes in a batch of rows and produces a *larger* batch by duplicating the rows and removing an element in each row based on a condition. For example, if the input batch looks like

```
[[4,  1, 10, 10,  2],
 [10, 7,  9, 10, 10],
 [6,  8, 10,  3,  5]]
```

Then the function should generate new samples based on the locations where **there is not a 10**. Those elements would be removed for each occurrence of a non-10 e.g. remove 4 from first sample (new sample), remove 1 (another new sample), ..., remove 5 from last sample. From the input batch, we would have 9 samples:

```
[[1, 10, 10, 2],
 [4, 10, 10, 2],
 [4, 1, 10, 10],
 [10, 9, 10, 10],
 [10, 7, 10, 10],
 [8, 10, 3, 5],
 [6, 10, 3, 5],
 [6, 8, 10, 5],
 [6, 8, 10, 3]]
```

Now to my function. Through the use of `tf.where`, `tf.gather`, `tf.unique_with_counts`, and `tf.repeat`, I am able to duplicate the original rows the correct number of times:

```py
def myFunction(data):
    # Returns a 2-column tensor, with each row
    # being the index pair...
    presentIndices = tf.where(data != 10)
    # Grab the 1st column (rows) and count how many
    # times each row appears...
    rows = tf.gather(presentIndices, indices=0, axis=1)
    _, _, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(rows)
    # Repeat each row according to counts...
    data = tf.repeat(data, repeats=counts, axis=0)
    # data now has 1st row copied 3 times, 2nd row copied twice, etc.
```

However, I am now stuck as to how to remove the proper elements from each row, given that I have the indices in `presentIndices`. With `numpy`, I can simply index `data` and reshape accordingly, but it appears that TensorFlow does not have nice capability of indexing into a multi-dimensional tensor.

I've looked into `tf.boolean_mask`, but that again I would need to assign `False` in the proper locations. The closest thing I can find is `tf.gather_nd`, but that **extracts** the data given the indices. Instead, I essentially need the negation of that function. Given the indices, extract all data **except** at those indices.

Is there a way to utilize the existing TensorFlow functions to get the functionality I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *tf.boolean_mask* and *tf.scatter_nd* to create a boolean vector for your (repeated)data.
First, you create an indices tensor to indicate the value to mask :

```
row = tf.constant([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] ,dtype = tf.int64)
mask_for_each_row = tf.stack([row ,presentIndices[: , 1]],axis = 1 )
```

and then you use mask_for_each_row as indices in *tf.scatter_nd* method :

```
samples =tf.boolean_mask(data ,~tf.scatter_nd(mask_for_each_row , 
            tf.ones((9,),dtype = tf.bool),(9,5)))
samples = tf.reshape(samples ,(9,4))
```

the samples tensor :

```
      <tf.Tensor: shape=(9, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
      array([[ 1, 10, 10,  2],
             [ 4, 10, 10,  2],
             [ 4,  1, 10, 10],
             [10,  9, 10, 10],
             [10,  7, 10, 10],
             [ 8, 10,  3,  5],
             [ 6, 10,  3,  5],
             [ 6,  8, 10,  5],
             [ 6,  8, 10,  3]])>
```

Comment: Cool thanks for your response! But are for loops allowed in a TensorFlow function that will eventually be mapped? When I tried to input this into my function, then called map on my function to a batch, it complained that "features were unsupported". Is there way to use a tf method to map this row-by-row operation?

Comment: Thanks. Just one note, I did end up replacing the `tf.constant([0,1,...,8])` with `tf.range(9)` because it's shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following. I know this might be a bit head-spinning. The easiest way would be just do an example using this code as a reference.

```
def f(data):
    
    # Boolean mask where it's not 10
    a = (data != 10)
    # Repeat and reshape to n x 5 x 5
    a = tf.reshape(tf.repeat(a, 5), [-1, 5, 5])
    # Create a identity matrix of size 1 x 5 x 5
    eye = tf.reshape(tf.eye(5), [1,5,5])
    # Create a mask of size n x 5 x 5. This basically forces a to have only a single false value for each row
    # This single false element is the element to be removed
    mask = ~tf.cast(tf.reshape(tf.cast(a,'int32')* tf.cast(eye, 'int32'), [-1, 5]), 'bool')

    # Remove all the rows with all elements True. This ensures at least one element is removed from all existing rows
    mask = tf.cast(mask, 'int32') * tf.cast(~tf.reduce_all(mask, axis=1, keepdims=True), 'int32')
    mask = tf.cast(mask, 'bool')
    
    # Get the required rows and discard others and reshape
    res = tf.boolean_mask(tf.repeat(data, 5, axis=0), mask)     
    res = tf.reshape(res, [-1,4])

    return res
```

This produces,

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 1 10 10  2]
 [ 4 10 10  2]
 [ 4  1 10 10]
 [10  9 10 10]
 [10  7 10 10]
 [ 8 10  3  5]
 [ 6 10  3  5]
 [ 6  8 10  5]
 [ 6  8 10  3]], shape=(9, 4), dtype=int32)
```